# Targeting tomcat 9 instead of 7 with JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jstl

I am trying to upgrade our tomcat from 7 to 9 and I have this error when tomcat tries to compile a jsp page.

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;Lorg/apache/jasper/runtime/Protect
edFunctionMapper;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:666)
```

Somehow tomcat is compiling JSP (JSTL actually) to an old version (I can see that in tomcat 7 the `proprietaryEvaluate` [function](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/runtime/PageContextImpl.html#proprietaryEvaluate(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext,%20org.apache.jasper.runtime.ProtectedFunctionMapper,%20boolean)) has a last parameter of type boolean which is not there in [tomcat 9](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/runtime/PageContextImpl.html#proprietaryEvaluate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext-org.apache.jasper.runtime.ProtectedFunctionMapper-)).

Where can I specify in my app that now I am targeting tomcat 9?

Thanks

Comment: This will happen when your webapp's WEB-INF/lib contains Tomcat libraries.

Comment: I have looked at the jars inside my WEB-INF/lib and the ones inside tomcat/lib but I didn't see any jar with the same name. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I guess there was some classpath issue, a redeploy solved the problem.

Comment: it may have been previously-generated & compiled JSPs sitting in the work/ or temp/ folders of your tomcat installation from the previous version of tomcat. Clearing those two folders solved the issue for me too